# Android Toast works in emulator but not on my device

Tags: android

I use this code in several places in my app:

```
Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "toast", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

When running in the emulator they almost always show.  The only times they don't show is when I'm debugging and take a long time to step through the code.

When I install the app on my device none of the Toasts work.  I didn't notice at first but I realized that I've never once seen them popup on my device.  Is that how Toasts work?

Edit:
I have tried these two alternatives:
Toast.makeText(this, "toast", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
Toast.makeText(ActivityName.this, "toast", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

Neither of these work.  All toasts work in the emulator (2.2, 2.3, 4.1) but none work on my device (Galaxy Nexus 4.1).

Comment: `Toast` notifications should definitely appear on the device. First thing that comes to mind is that I've heard `getApplicationContext()` can be a bit shady. Perhaps try with `.getContext()` from any known `View`, if possible. Also, do you see `Toast`s from other applications? (Can't think of a place to check for them off the top of my head...)

Comment: ActivityName.this instead of getAppliationContext()

Comment: When I try to display a toast on a button click I changed my code to view.getContext().  That still worked in my emulator, but not on my device.  I've also tried ActivityName.this and that also worked in the emulator, but not on my device.  I have noticed other devices do show the toast so I wonder if my device is the issue not the code.

Answer (score 10):

I had this problem, and found out that I had set my app in the device settings to not show any notifications. After I allowed for notifications under the device settings, everything worked just fine.

Hopefully this will help some other poor soul not spend an afternoon finding the answer.

Comment: I was potentially that poor soul.  I never would have thought of this.  You saved me at least an afternoon.  Great work!

Answer (score 0):

The line you wrote to show the Toast is 100% correct and toast should come up. There is no error in it.

Problem is in like, where you wrote those lines..!!

---

To know the actual problem one will need to check and `debug` your entire code.

But while it comes to guessing the problem there may be,

1. You have put your `Toast` in certain `if..else` condition which is not getting true
2. `Toast` in the part of code where *the execution control don't go*
3. `String` *variables* appended with `Toast` string and those variables are `null`
4. Just to check, replace your `Toast` with `Log` and see what happens.

Comment: Thank you for the advice.  The issue is that the Toasts show up in the emulator.  They also show up in Log if I change it to that.  However, they do not show up on my specific device.  I found that they do show up on other people's devices so that confuses me more.